# Basis of convex and concave functions

Tags: convex-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $g(t)$ be a positive function.  I'm trying to show that the set $\{ |t|^ne^{\frac{g(t)}{t^n}}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is linearly independent in the space of measurable functions on $\mathbb{R}$ (ie: $L^0(\mathbb{R})$).

I tried working in a weighted $L^2_w(\mathbb{R})$ space but these are not orthogonal so I can't use that type of argument, an

Comment: Those functions are not defined on $\mathbb{R}$ due to singularity in the exponent when $t=0$.

Comment: If you consider those functions $h_n(t)$ defined over $t \in [1,\infty)$ and you assume $g(t)$ is bounded above, you could inductively show that $\{h_1(t), h_2(t), ..., h_k(t)\}$ are linearly independent, i.e., $\sum_{i=1}^ka_i h_i(t) = 0 \implies $ all $a_i=0$.  Just consider limiting behavior as $t\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: Thanks, also it doesn't matter if they are "not defined on $\mathbb{R}$ because they are indeed a.s. defined (wrt any diffuse measure).